# can't get bootstrap's input select dropdown box working with django for loop

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I can't get my django working correctly with bootstrap when I use input select.
The label and box appears, but with nothing in it. Underneath the box I see all my equipment ids. I can't get them into the box. what am I missing?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="equipment_id" control-label">{{ form.equipment_id.label }}</label> 
    {% for equip in form.equipment_id %}
        <select id="equipment_id" name="equipment_id" class="form-control">
            <option>{{ equip }}</option>
        </select>
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ form.equipment_id.errors.as_text }}</p>
</div>
```

**NEW**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap %} <!--using app `django-bootstrap-form` app name: `bootstrapform` -->
{% block content %}


<div class="container">

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <legend>Report Incident</legend>

        {{ form.incident_date_time_occurred|bootstrap_horizontal }}
        {{ form.incident_category|bootstrap_horizontal }}
        {{ form.clinical_sample|bootstrap_horizontal }}
        {{ form.number_of_clinical_samples|bootstrap_horizontal }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <p>(If not a clinical sample please leave as zero)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <select multiple="multiple" class=" form-control" id="id_multiple_choice" name="multiple_choice">
        {% for tech in form.technician %}
        <option>{{ tech }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form> 
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Incident(models.Model):
       incident_date_time_reported = models.DateTimeField('incident reported', default=timezone.now)
       user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
       incident_date_time_occurred = models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now)
       clinical_sample = models.BooleanField('clinical sample?', default=True)
       number_of_clinical_samples = models.IntegerField('Number of clinical samples', default=0)
       sample_id_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=500)
       equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
       incident_category = models.ForeignKey(Incident_Category)
       technician = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='technician')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this div is properly contained within a form tag:

1. You should be using form.equipment, equipment_id only has the ID numbers.
2. You're trying to iterate to create options, but your select tag is inside the for loop, so you're creating one select for each equipment object, instead of one option for each.
3. Without the rest of your code, it's unclear if there are other problems.

I assume what you're trying to do is get the form to display with bootstrap attributes. A much cleaner solution is to use the package django-bootstrap-forms (`pip install django-bootstrap-forms`), include it in your template with `{% load bootstrap %}`, and use as follows:

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button id="create_submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

You're still iterating over options incorrectly. Correct would be something like:

```
{% for value,text in form.technician.choices %}
    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

You might run into problems actually posting the form if technician is a foreign key field (only one allowed per model instance). But that's a separate issue :)

Comment: This is great! I switched over to the bootstrapform app but I still can't get multiple select to work for `technicians`. I will post the updated code above and the changes I made.

Comment: If I answered your original question, please accept the answer rather than changing the question. I'd be happy to help with additional problems here in the comments section.

Comment: It didn't help me get the multiple select working, which was my original question, but it did introduce me to something new `bootstrapform`. I checked it correct anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It is a foreign key field. er

Comment: In the docs it says: Add "bootstrapform" to your INSTALLED_APPS.